# Forgot Password link for split username based login Page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

We have implemented the split username login page, where the first page will take only username and the second page will take password and PIN, we have to add the forgot password link in the second page.

I have tried the code given in the Microsoft documentation, but that doesn't work with the username based sign in .

Could you please suggest of there are any ways to implement this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

I have tried the mentioned steps for username based sign in profiles, but that doesnot showing the password link in the second page.

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) you are following is correct, *please try rechecking whether you have missed any step.*

> **If you are still facing the issue, please go through the below workarounds:**

- Try setting up the force password reset flow by using this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/force-password-reset?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).
- Otherwise, try setting up Sign-up and Sign-in with [embedded password reset.](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset)
- To add forgot password link make use of [custom policy starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/archive/master.zip) , as it is included in all the template by default.
- Make sure  ***setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation***  Metadata key is NOT present under  ***TechnicalProfile***.

Please go through below **references** if they are helpful,

[Azure Active Directory B2C: Add Forgot password Link in my custom sign in policy - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/290029/azure-active-directory-b2c-add-forgot-password-lin.html).

[Azure AD B2C Password Reset (newbedev.com)](https://newbedev.com/azure-ad-b2c-password-reset).